# Paperclip-av-transcoder not generating thumbnails in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

I am using paperclip-ac-transcoder gem for uploading videos in my rails app. Now, the videos are being successfully saved at the application path, but it's not generating the thumbnails for it. Moreover, the video_tag is not working to display the video also.

Below is my code :-

```
has_attached_file :movie,
 :url => ":assets_host/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
 :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",
 :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mov', :streaming => true },
 :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'png', :time => 10 },
 :processors => [:transcoder], :swallow_stderr => false
```

For video tag I am using the following:-

```
<%= video_tag "#{:rails_root}/public/system/sources/uploaded_movies/movies/10/original/MyMov.mov", :size => "320x240", :controls => true %>
```

Please guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No answers dear members ?? No help ??

Comment: This is a known issue in the gem. https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder/issues/2

Answer (score 0):

That was a known issue with the gem that has been fixed. Try upgrading to the latest version.